# What's the meaning of " a blue berserk"?

Tags: meaning

Dis married Jokul Ironback, **a blue berserk**.

From "The Saga of Thorstein Viking's Son" by R.B.Anderson.

It's a norse saga that I'm reading. What's the meaning of "a blue berserk", I know the word "berserk" is a Norse warrior, but "blue", I really don't know.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing that the berserk in question painted himself with woad.

Comment: Maybe he's sad, because he's not single anymore. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion of a blue berserk mixes together two mostly-unrelated cases: that of Berserkers, or berserks, “Norse warriors who are primarily reported in the Old Norse literature to have fought in a nearly uncontrollable, trance-like fury” [1] and Celtic warriors, which “Julius Caesar in his Commentaries on the Gallic Wars” described as dyeing their skins blue [2].

Note that while *woad* [3] (or, *Isatis tinctoria* [4]) produces a nice blue dye, it is not at all clear that woad actually was used by Celtic warriors for skin dyeing.  Source [2] says: “experimentation suggests that woad is not very well suited as a skin dye nor as tattoo ink”, and source [4] suggests that the *vitrum* coloring agent mentioned by Julius Caesar may instead have been “some form of copper- or iron-based pigment”.

[1] [Wikipedia, *Berserker*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berserker)
[2] [Wikipedia, *Celtic warfare*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celtic_warfare) 
[3] [Wiktionary, *woad*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/woad)
[4] [Wikipedia, *Isatis tinctoria*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isatis_tinctoria)

Comment: A perfectly correct answer -- this must not be the internet :)